# SpringBoot: How to rollback creation of parent if child creation fails?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two models namely **Company** and **User**. 
A Company can have many Users. I use Spring data jpa to interact with the database.

**User Model :**

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(length = 50, unique = true)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 4, max = 50)
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 8)
    private String password;

    @Column(length = 50)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 4, max = 50)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(length = 50)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 4, max = 50)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(length = 50, unique = true)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 4, max = 50)
    private String email;

    private Boolean enabled = true;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Date lastPasswordReset;

    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdAt = new Date();

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @UpdateTimestamp
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date updatedAt = new Date();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_authority",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "authority_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    private List<Authority> authorities;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Company company;

... Getter and Setters
}
```

**Company Model**

```
@Entity
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 4, max = 100)
    private String name;

    @Size(max = 500)
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

...Followed by Getter and Setters
}
```

So I use Spring Data JPA to save Company which takes care of creating a User as well. 
So today if for some reason the creation of user fails due to some exception, the company record still exists.
So I need that if creation of User fails the Company shall not be created(rollback).
How can I achieve this.

Comment: Do you do compnay + user creations in a single transaction or do you use multiple transactions?

Comment: Single transaction, I just call CompanyRepository which ectends JpaRepository,and call the save(Entity e) method proved by it by passing company as entity.

Comment: So how is CompanyRepository creating users?

Comment: Because I'm using Casacade.
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();